# Material Design (WPF): Remove CheckBox Background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I'm trying to display the square and the check mark only when the `CheckBox` is checked.

My code is as follows:

```
<CheckBox Content="Teste">
     <CheckBox.Resources>
           <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialDesignCheckBoxOff" Color="White"/>
           <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
     </CheckBox.Resources>
</CheckBox>
```

But, it doesn't work, when removing the background the enable mark disappears.

Image of how I want to leave my `CheckBox`:

[image: Image of how the CheckBox should look]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an easy thing to do, but it is not. The default template of the `CheckBox` in MaterialDesign uses a `Path` to draw the box and the check mark. In fact, it reuses the same `Path`, but only changes its `Data` property.

- The `Path` is defined with its [normal state](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/e799b0cbcef70f5d9be2e502223244bdb2d58783/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.CheckBox.xaml#L98) (just the empty box)

  ```
  <Path x:Name="Graphic"
        Data="M19,3H5C3.89,3 3,3.89 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V5C21,3.89 20.1,3 19,3M19,5V19H5V5H19Z" 
        Fill="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignCheckBoxOff}" />
  ```

  [image: Example of the empty check box]
- The [checked trigger](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/e799b0cbcef70f5d9be2e502223244bdb2d58783/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.CheckBox.xaml#L131) for example changes the `Data` property to display a filled box. What you see is actually the filled box being drawn and the check mark in it is just not filled at all, it is a gap.

  ```
  <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
     <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="Graphic" Value="M10,17L5,12L6.41,10.58L10,14.17L17.59,6.58L19,8M19,3H5C3.89,3 3,3.89 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V5C21,3.89 20.1,3 19,3Z" />
     <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Graphic" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" />
  </Trigger>
  ```

  [image: Example of checked check box]

As you can see, changing the `MaterialDesignCheckBoxOff` brush does not work as you expect, because the check mark is not a separate element with a separate color.

If you want to change this, you will have to adapt the control templates that can be found [in the GitHub repository](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.CheckBox.xaml). You would have to copy the default templates and styles to create a separate check mark and background path and set their colors accordingly. After that, you would include these styles in a resource dictionary and use them as named resources or create implicit styles and override the styles provied by *MaterialDesign* for the `CheckBox`.